# Unable to print all property's name of an Active Directory object

Tags: c++, c, c++11, active-directory

I am trying to print the names of all the properties of an Active Directory object using the below code:

```
HRESULT ActiveDirectoryWrapper::PrintAllProperties(IADs *pADs) {
    IADsPropertyList *pPList = NULL;
    // Getting info of object
    pADs->GetInfo();
    HRESULT hr = pADs->QueryInterface(IID_IADsPropertyList, (void**)&pPList);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the number of properties in the object
        LONG lCount = 0;
        hr = pPList->get_PropertyCount(&lCount);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Iterate over the object's properties and print their names and values
            for (LONG i = 0; i < lCount; i++)
            {
                // Retrieve the property name
                VARIANT propertyName;
                VariantInit(&propertyName);
                propertyName.vt = VT_EMPTY;
                hr = pPList->Next(&propertyName);

                printf("\tProperty name: %S\n", propertyName.bstrVal);
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    pPList->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

Currently, the problem I am facing is it's able to loop through all the properties but it's printing the property name empty.

> For e.g.
>
> Let's suppose there are 4 properties for an IADs object, so it will
> print Property name: Property name: Property name: Property name:

It tried to print the Property name as `V_BSTR(&propertyName)` but still the results were the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `IADsPropertyList::Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadspropertylist-next#parameters) describes the out value like this:

> `[out] pVariant`
>
> Address of a caller-allocated variable that contains the value of the next item in the property list. The return value of VT_DISPATCH refers to an [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) interface pointer to an object implementing the [IADsPropertyEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadspropertyentry) interface.

The key words being "return value of VT_DISPATCH". So you need to call `V_DISPATCH(&propertyName)` to be able to use the object. But then you still need to call [`QueryInterface()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)) on it to be able to use it as an `IADsPropertyEntry` object.

The [documentation for IADsPropertyEntry Property Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/iadspropertyentry-property-methods#examples) has a C++ example of printing a property name. Using that, your code should look something like this:

```
HRESULT ActiveDirectoryWrapper::PrintAllProperties(IADs *pADs) {
    IADsPropertyList *pPList = NULL;
    // Getting info of object
    pADs->GetInfo();
    HRESULT hr = pADs->QueryInterface(IID_IADsPropertyList, (void**)&pPList);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the number of properties in the object
        LONG lCount = 0;
        hr = pPList->get_PropertyCount(&lCount);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Iterate over the object's properties and print their names and values
            for (LONG i = 0; i < lCount; i++)
            {
                // Retrieve the property name
                VARIANT propertyName;
                VariantInit(&propertyName);
                hr = pPList->Next(&propertyName);
                
                IADsPropertyEntry *pEntry = NULL;
                hr = V_DISPATCH(&propertyName)->QueryInterface(IID_IADsPropertyEntry,
                                      (void**)&pEntry);
                                      
                BSTR nm = NULL;
                hr = pEntry->get_Name(&nm);

                printf("\tProperty name: %S\n", nm);
                
                VariantClear(&propertyName);
                pEntry->Release();
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    pPList->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

For simplicity I didn't check the value of `hr`, but you may want to for the sake of being safe.

Answer (score -1):

What if you call the VariantInit() method first? You also need to release it first using VariantClear() as described here: [Microsoft VariantClear Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-variantclear)

```html
HRESULT ActiveDirectoryWrapper::PrintAllProperties(IADs *pADs) {
    IADsPropertyList *pPList = NULL;
    // Getting info of object
    pADs->GetInfo();
    HRESULT hr = pADs->QueryInterface(IID_IADsPropertyList, (void**)&pPList);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the number of properties in the object
        LONG lCount = 0;
        hr = pPList->get_PropertyCount(&lCount);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Iterate over the object's properties and print their names and values
            for (LONG i = 0; i < lCount; i++)
            {
                // Retrieve the property name
                VARIANT propertyName;
                VariantInit(&propertyName);
                propertyName.vt = VT_EMPTY;
                hr = pPList->Next(&propertyName);

                // Print the property name
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    printf("\tProperty name: %ls\n", propertyName.bstrVal);
                    VariantClear(&propertyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    pPList->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

Lastly, watch out for `printf()` it can be a security vulnerability as cited here: [How to exploit printf](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105956/how-to-exploit-this-piece-of-code-format-string-in-printf)

Comment: Still, the property name is empty, also I am unable to figure out the difference between your code and mine.

Comment: You can't figure out the difference? Use a text compare utility or something.. or you know. Read it. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Anyways the outcome is similar in both the case.

Answer (score -1):

From Microsoft learn site, see details below.

The following code example shows how to retrieve a property entry using the GetPropertyItem method. It assumes that the IADsPropertyList interface has been properly retrieved. For more information about how to load the property cache, see the GetPropertyCache example function in IADsPropertyList.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadspropertylist-getpropertyitem

```
#include <activeds.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to retrieve a specified property entry 
// using the IADsPropertyList::GetPropertyItem method.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
IADsPropertyEntry *GetPropertyItem(
      IADsPropertyList *pList, 
      BSTR entryName,
      long entryType)
{
   IADsPropertyEntry *pEntry;
   VARIANT var;
   VariantInit(&var);

   if(!pList || !entryName)
   {
      _tprintf("Invalid argument...");
      return NULL;
   }
 
   // Get a property entry.
   hr = pList->GetPropertyItem(entryName, entryType, &var);
   hr = V_DISPATCH(&var)->QueryInterface(IID_IADsPropertyEntry,
                                         (void**)&pEntry);
   VariantClear(&var);
 
   return pEntry;
}
 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Examine a property entry.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
IADsPropertyList *pList = NULL;
IADsPropertyEntry *pEntry = NULL;

pList = GetPropertyCache(L"LDAP://dc01/DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM");
 
if(pList)
{
    pEntry = GetPropertyItem(pList, L"dc", ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING);
}

if(pEntry)
{ 
    BSTR nm;
    HRESULT hr = pEntry->get_Name(&nm);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        printf("Property name = %S\n",nm);
        SysFreeString(nm);
    }
}
 
if(pList)
    pList->Release();
if(pEntry)
    pEntry->Release();
```

Comment: I am also retrieving PropertyList correctly, there is something missing while getting the property name.